# First hide then Show multiple tbody groups based on a dropdown selection using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I an trying to first show only the first tbody (in a table with a thead and multiple tbody grouping) on page load and then show the rest of the tbody based on a change in a dropdown selection using jQuery

Here is a sample of the code.

```js
//here is the custom JS we would like to add
$("#choice").change(function() {
  $("#table tbody tr").hide();
  $("#table tbody tr." + $(this).val()).show('fast');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choice">
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option value="1Year">1 Year</option>
  <option value="1.25Years">1 Year 3 Months</option>
  <option value="1.5Years">1 Year 6 Months</option>
  <option value="2Years">2 Years</option>
</select>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>



  <tbody id="1Year">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="1.25Years">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="1.5Years">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like Show the first six months of the calculator content and give users the option to display the rest of the table (calculator) content for several years when they select the option on the dropdown.

Kindly assist.

Comment: For your own sake I'd suggest *not* using IDs with decimals in them. Just makes it harder to select them, as `.` is a reserved selector character. (It can be escaped easily enough, just seems like an unnecessary pain.)

Comment: Also, your selector seems to be hiding/showing `<tr>` elements by *class*, as opposed to `<tbody>` elements by *ID*.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response@Tyler I will make sure i avoid the . in the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Start by doing what you say you are doing - hide tbody and not trs
- Then make sure there are no special chars in the ID and that it starts with a letter or underscore - it makes your life easier in jQuery
- Since IDs need to be unique, you can access them directly
- You do need an ID on the table to do #table tbody too
- Also give the Choose a blank value
- I added selected to the 1year to be able to trigger change on it on load to handle "*show only the first tbody  on page load*"
- I also added t2Years to the table

```js
//here is the custom JS we would like to add
$("#choice").on("change",function() {
  $("#table>tbody").hide();
  if (this.value) $("#t" + this.value).show('fast');
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choice">
  <option value="">Choose...</option>
  <option selected value="1Year">1 Year</option>
  <option value="1_25Years">1 Year 3 Months</option>
  <option value="1_5Years">1 Year 6 Months</option>
  <option value="2Years">2 Years</option>
</select>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Table header</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>



  <tbody id="t1Year">
    <tr>
      <td>1 year</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="t1_25Years">
    <tr>
      <td>1.25</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="t1_5Years">
    <tr>
      <td>1.5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody id="t2Years">
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Will do. I tried the code above. Is there a way i can have a tbody (without ID) between the thead and the tbody with the ID so that this tbody without ID is displayed permanently....and the once with ID display only when selected.This is because when a user select ..Choose... it leaves the whole table blank.

Comment: Also to have the select options in the above code settle on Choose rather than 1 year......Displaying only the permanent tbody.....I'll really appreciate.

Comment: Just give choose the selected and give choose a value of 1year

Comment: Or remove choose

Comment: Thank you @Mplungjan. I have understood  that part.  I will implement it. [link](http://flamepassion.com/PassionateAssetsPortfolio/calculator/)

Answer (score 1):

--------- REDACTED (This is all wrong :P) ------

An ID or class can't start with a number. e.g. 1Year should be changed to Year1. Also you can't use `.` in a class or id. e.g. 1.25Years should be changed to Years1-25.

------ REDACTED ------

**NOTE of redaction:** Numbers are now allowed at the beginning of classes and ids in html5. Periods are also allowed in ids, just be sure to escape the period in your CSS. e.g. `#1\.25Years`

---

**Actual issue with code**

Your jquery selector was selecting an element with an id of table, rather than the table. Also you were selecting a tr with a class of the selected options value rather than the id of the tbody. I have changed it so the table is selected and the id of the tbody is selected.

```js
//here is the custom JS we would like to add
$("#choice").change(function() {
  $("table tbody").hide();
  $("table tbody#" + $(this).val()).show('fast');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choice">
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option value="Year1">1 Year</option>
  <option value="Years1-25">1 Year 3 Months</option>
  <option value="Years1-5">1 Year 6 Months</option>
  <option value="Years2">2 Years</option>
</select>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="Year1">
    <tr>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="Years1-25">
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="Years1-5">
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
  <tbody id="Years2">
    <tr>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: *"An ID or class can't start with a number"* ... not true in html5 spec and dot is also allowed in id

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for clarifying. I wasn't aware of that change.

Comment: an id can have virtually any character except space and can be numeric also

Answer (score 0):

I have arrived at the final solution to the problem above.
Users will have a header and a few rows of the data permanently displayed (grouped under the thead).
Upon loading of the page, the selected will settle on choose (displaying none of the tbody groups) and have the option to extent the data by selecting option in the dropdown menu at the top. The tbody groups will display at the bottom of the permanent rows:

A big thank you to all those who contributed.

See final code below:

```js
//here is the custom JS we would like to add
$("#choice").on("change",function() {
  $("#table>tbody").hide();
  if (this.value) $("#t" + this.value).show('fast');
}).change();
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choice">
  <option selected value="">Choose...</option>
  <option value="1Year">1 Year</option>
  <option value="1_25Years">1 Year 3 Months</option>
  <option value="1_5Years">1 Year 6 Months</option>
  <option value="2Years">2 Years</option>
</select>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Table header</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Permanent row 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Permanent row 2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>



  <tbody id="t1Year">
    <tr>
      <td>1 year</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="t1_25Years">
    <tr>
      <td>1.25</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="t1_5Years">
    <tr>
      <td>1.5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody id="t2Years">
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I have copied the above final code exactly as it is into a test  - php file in a wordpress twenty seventeen child theme. But its not executing as in the solution above. It is displaying everything and the select option not working either. What could i be doing wrong?  See : [link](http://flamepassion.com/PassionateAssetsPortfolio/test1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have researched anc came up with these.

See code:

```js
//here is the custom JS we would like to add
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('tbody').hide();
      
$("#choice").change(function() {
  $("table>tbody").hide();
  $("table>tbody#" + $(this).val()).show('fast');
});
 });
```

```html
     <html>  
     <body>
      
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="choice">
      <option selected value="">Choose...</option>
      <option value="Year1">1 Year</option>
      <option value="Years1-25">1 Year 3 Months</option>
      <option value="Years1-5">1 Year 6 Months</option>
      <option value="Years2">2 Years</option>
    </select>

    <table id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
        </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
        </tr> 
     <tr>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
        </tr>   
      </thead>

      <tbody id="Year1">
        <tr>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tbody id="Years1-25">
        <tr>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tbody id="Years1-5">
        <tr>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      
      <tbody id="Years2">
        <tr>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
        </tr>
        
        
      </tbody>
    </table>

     
       </body> 
       </html>
```