# hide tbody on page load, show thead group permanently, tbody on dropdown selection using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to first show only thead and a few rows of the data (permanently display data grouped under the thead) on page load. Upon loading of the page,I want the selected to settle on choose (displaying none of the tbody groups) and Give users the option to extent the data by selecting option in the dropdown menu at the top (to display the selected tbody). The tbody groups will display at the bottom of the permanent rows. This code doesn't hide the tbody on page load but does the rest of what i want it to do.

See my previous question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57040950/first-hide-then-show-multiple-tbody-groups-based-on-a-dropdown-selection-using-j/57041084#57041084)

Kindly assist.

Here is a sample of the code.

```js
//here is the custom JS we would like to add
$("#choice").change(function() {
  $("table tbody").hide();
  $("table tbody#" + $(this).val()).show('fast');
});
```

```html
 <html>  
 <body>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choice">
  <option selected value="">Choose...</option>
  <option value="Year1">1 Year</option>
  <option value="Years1-25">1 Year 3 Months</option>
  <option value="Years1-5">1 Year 6 Months</option>
  <option value="Years2">2 Years</option>
</select>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
    </tr> 
 <tr>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
    </tr>   
  </thead>

  <tbody id="Year1">
    <tr>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="Years1-25">
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="Years1-5">
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
  <tbody id="Years2">
    <tr>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

 
   </body> 
   </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have done some research and came up with a solution to this.

See below:

```js
//here is the custom JS we would like to add
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('tbody').hide();
      
$("#choice").change(function() {
  $("table>tbody").hide();
  $("table>tbody#" + $(this).val()).show('fast');
});
 });
```

```html
     <html>  
     <body>
      
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="choice">
      <option selected value="">Choose...</option>
      <option value="Year1">1 Year</option>
      <option value="Years1-25">1 Year 3 Months</option>
      <option value="Years1-5">1 Year 6 Months</option>
      <option value="Years2">2 Years</option>
    </select>

    <table id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
          <th>hello</th>
        </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
          <td>Permanentrow1</td>
        </tr> 
     <tr>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
          <td>Permanentrow2</td>
        </tr>   
      </thead>

      <tbody id="Year1">
        <tr>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
          <td>Year1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tbody id="Years1-25">
        <tr>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
          <td>Years1-25</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tbody id="Years1-5">
        <tr>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
          <td>Years1-5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      
      <tbody id="Years2">
        <tr>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
          <td>Years2</td>
        </tr>
        
        
      </tbody>
    </table>

     
       </body> 
       </html>
```

Comment: If you hide the tbody elements with CSS you won't get that flicker at page load.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: none` to your `<tbody>`

```js
//here is the custom JS we would like to add
$("#choice").change(function() {
  $("table tbody").hide()
  val = $(this).val()
  if (val != '') {
    $("table tbody#" + val).show('fast')
  }
});
```

```css
table tbody {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<html> 
 <body>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choice">
  <option selected value="">Choose...</option>
  <option value="Year1">1 Year</option>
  <option value="Years1-25">1 Year 3 Months</option>
  <option value="Years1-5">1 Year 6 Months</option>
  <option value="Years2">2 Years</option>
</select>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th>hello</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
      <td>Permanentrow1</td>
    </tr> 
 <tr>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
      <td>Permanentrow2</td>
    </tr>   
  </thead>

  <tbody id="Year1">
    <tr>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
      <td>Year1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="Years1-25">
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
      <td>Years1-25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="Years1-5">
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
      <td>Years1-5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
  <tbody id="Years2">
    <tr>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
      <td>Years2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

 
   </body> 
   </html>
```

**EDIT :** Fix change function